# ACF v4 addons visibility

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I have WordPress 3.5.1 installed, with the [Advanced Custom Fields Plugin](http://advancedcustomfields.com) `(ACF) v.4` and two `ACF` add-ons installed (Repeater and Flexible Field).

In ACF (`*Custom Fields > Add-ons*`) they seem to be installed properly. However, I cannot see them anywhere in WP admin menu. I'm stuck with basic functionality.

I searched on `ACF` website, but there doesn't seem to be any answer, nor even any questions regarding my problem. Any ideas how to make them usable?

Comment: Yes, ACF and the two addons are all active. As I said, I can use ACF, just not the addons.

Comment: Perhaps you have to downgrade the Wordpress version to the 3.5. because I can read **Compatible up to: 3.5.0** on the plugin page.

Comment: I've only found `Tested up to: 3.5.0` in readme file. Is there some other place where they specify the maximum WP version?

Comment: `Compatible up to: 3.5.0` is on the WP plugin page http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: Oh well. Seems I really need to downgrade. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You welcome. Good luck for the downgrade (not fun).

Comment: And please confirm the compatibility so I can create a clear answer for other users.

Comment: Just installed WP 3.5.0 and using the same addons, the situation repeats. The only usable plugin is ACF itself.

Comment: Still using the version beta (v4.0.0) of ACF?

Comment: Correct. Attempting to install ACF from Wordpress plugin repository results in getting an installation that does not work at all.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [WordPress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @DiH If it can help you I have a successful instal for WP 3.5.1 with ACF v3.5.8.1 (add-on repeater activated).

Comment: @Adnan Sorry but I dont understand when a question on Wordpress have to go here or to WordPress.SE...

Comment: @jeromeM, honestly, me neither. But the way I see it is this. If it was a coding questions that involves the usage of WordPress, then it's StackOverflow with WP tag. But if it's a question about WordPress itself (such as this one) and/or its plugins, then it should be on WP.SE. I hope I'm correct.

Comment: @Adnan thank you for these explanations, clear for me now.

Comment: @jeromeM It worked with configuration you posted, that is WP 3.5.1 and ACF 3.5.8.1. Could you post it as an answer? I also managed to make the previous configurations work with re-installing all the plugins again, on a separate host. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time the package coming from WordPress is not delivering the full latest version of ACF.

You can find the full version here (actually the 3.5.8.1):
https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf/archive/master.zip

Compatibility checked here with success (ACF and add-ons):

```
WordPress: 3.5.1
ACF: 3.5.8.
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 19.02.2013 it is necessary to install ACF from [author's github repository](https://github.com/elliotcondon/). Both versions: [`ACF 3.5.8`](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf/) and [`ACF 4.0.0`](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf4) are working properly with both `WP 3.5.1` and `WP 3.5`.

For `ACF 3.5.8` it's still possible to install older addons by entering activations codes in plugin settings, however the new ones have to be installed, uploaded and activated in Wordpress manually using [the following link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons-download/).